# Changing style properties on a variable not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, styles

Using `document.querySelector( element ).style.property = value;` seems to work 100% of the time.

However if I were to put this elements style properties into a variable and try to set a value - this always seems to fail:

```
let div1 = document.querySelector( 'div:nth-of-type( 1 )' );
let div1Filter = div1.style.filter;

div1Filter = 'blur( 0.25rem )'; //Why does this fail?
```

```js
let div1 = document.querySelector( 'div:nth-of-type( 1 )' ),
    div2 = document.querySelector( 'div:nth-of-type( 2 )' ),
    div3 = document.querySelector( 'div:nth-of-type( 3 )' ),
    div4 = document.querySelector( 'div:nth-of-type( 4 )' );
    
let div1Filter = div1.style.filter;

div1Filter = 'blur( 0.25rem )'; //Why does this fail?

//div1.style.filter = 'blur( 0.25rem )';  //But this work?
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
div {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: #eee;
}
div ~ div {
  transform: scale( 0.8 );
  filter: brightness( 80% );
}
div ~ div ~ div {
  transform: scale( 0.6 );
  filter: brightness( 60% );
}
div ~ div ~ div ~ div {
  transform: scale( 0.4 );
  filter: brightness( 40% );
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

So my question is how can I put an element's style inside a variable and set it to a value?

*( In this specific case - how can I set `div1`'s CSS filter value to `blur( 0.25rem )` using the `div1Filter` variable )*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

element.style.filter can't be referenced I believe.

```
var ref = element.style.filter // You are assigning the value of filter to ref, not assigning the property itself
```

But you can certainly assign this kind of reference:

```
var ref = element.style // this way your are refering to the style object inside element which houses the property filter you wanted
```

before doing something to it:

```
 ref.filter= 'blah blah'
```

Look at this example:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdgyW.png)

Comment: So i can save the `element.style` in a variable and set it but not a property like `element.style.opacity`?

Comment: Also can you provide a working example in a snippet because `let div1Style = div1.style;` `div1Style = 'filter: blur( 0.25rem )';` isn't working for me either.

Comment: Yes, certainly. Try it on dev console. element.style returns the object containing all styling properties of the element

Comment: correction: div1Style.filter = 'blur( 0.25rem )';

Comment: stored in the div1style are the style, so to access filter you have to call it.

You can also: div1style.color='#000'